# How do I use SQL Server 2016 to pattern match against strings in a table without using a cursor?

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

**Color** table:

```
  ID    Color
+-----+---------+
|  1  | Red     |
+-----+---------+
|  2  | Blue    |
+-----+---------+
|  3  | Green   |
+-----+---------+
```

I want to search strings for any of the colors in the table and return the ID of the color found. If not found then the resulting temp table has no rows.

For example, a strings to search might be

```
'Today we have the blue plate special'
'The light is red'
'That is lemon yellow' -- this won't be found
```

I can use a cursor:

```
DECLARE @index INT
DECLARE @str nchar(50) = 'Today we have the blue plate special'

DECLARE @colors TABLE
                (
                    id INT,
                    color NCHAR(20)
                )

DECLARE Color_Cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT Id, Color 
    FROM ColorTable;

DECLARE @colorId INT
DECLARE @matchColor nchar (10)

OPEN Color_Cursor;  

FETCH NEXT FROM Color_Cursor into @colorId, @matchColor;  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    SELECT 
        @index = CHARINDEX(LTRIM(RTRIM(@matchColor)), 
        @str COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) 

    IF (@index <> 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @colors (id, color) 
            (SELECT @colorId, @matchColor)
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM Color_Cursor into @colorId, @matchColor; 
END;  

CLOSE Color_Cursor;  
DEALLOCATE Color_Cursor;  

SELECT * FROM @colors
```

Result is:

```
+-----+---------+
|  2  | Blue    |
+-----+---------+
```

Works but it seems I should be able to do this without a cursor. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `LIKE` operator with the case-insensitive collation specified:

```
WITH ColorTable(ID, Color) As
(
    SELECT 1, 'Red' Union
    SELECT 2, 'Blue' union
    SELECT 3, 'Green'
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ColorTable 
WHERE 
    'Today we have the blue plate special' LIKE '%' + Color + '%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Results:

```
ID | Color
---+------
 2 | Blue
```

If you have another table with the sentences you want to test, you can do a join between the two using the same comparison as the join condition:

```
WITH ColorTable(ID, Color) As
(
    SELECT 1, 'Red' Union
    SELECT 2, 'Blue' union
    SELECT 3, 'Green'
)
, Sentences(Sentence) AS
(
    SELECT 'Today we have the blue plate special' UNION
    SELECT 'The light is red' UNION
    SELECT 'That is lemon yellow'  UNION
    SELECT 'A red fox jumped over a green bucket'
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Sentences s
JOIN
    ColorTable c
    ON
    s.Sentence LIKE '%' + c.Color + '%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

This will return a row for each color found in each sentence:

```
Sentence                             | ID | Color
-------------------------------------+----+------
The light is red                     |  1 | Red
Today we have the blue plate special |  2 | Blue
A red fox jumped over a green bucket |  1 | Red
A red fox jumped over a green bucket |  3 | Green
```

Comment: Thought there was a much better way. At least I learned something about cursors.

Comment: Note: You could use the `CHARINDEX` solution you had in your cursor, which may actually be better performance wise, in place of my `LIKE` solution. I think all you were really in need of was the `JOIN` instead of the `CURSOR`. In general, a `CURSOR` should be an absolute last resort -- there is almost always a solution that doesn't use one.